# Problems adding supervisors and list some to the right and some to the left of the page

Tags: thesis

I am using following template:
https://da.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/laursen's-thesis

I want to add supervisors to the static part and because I cooperate with two departments I want the supervisors from department Y to be on the right side of the page and those from department X to be on the left side of the page, but on same lines. As an example how I would like it to be:

```
Supervisors:
Department X;                                   Department Y;
A.B.                                            W.K.
C.D.                                            L.J
```

How can I do this? And how can I change the letter size?

The static parts looks like this now:

```
\def\thesistypeabbr{MSc.}
\def\thesistype    {Master of Science in Engineering}
\def\thesistitle   {Bacteria}
\def\thesisauthor {Me}
\Supervisors{Department X; A.B. and C.D.\\ Department Y; W.K. and L.J.} 
\def\thesislocation{City}
\def\papersize    {a4paper}
\def\showtrims    {false}
\def\showtodos    {true}
\def\confidential {false}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: In the template you linked to there is no definition of the macro `\Supervisors` contained.

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess because you don't show us which `\documentclass` and packages you use. But the following could work:

```
\Supervisors{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l@{}}
    Department X; & Department Y;\\
    A.B.          & W.K.\\
    C.D.          & L.J.
  \end{tabular*}%
}
```

Using your template I changed the stuff contained in `./prefrontmatter/titlepage.tex` to the following (changes are marked using comments):

```
%!TEX root = ../Thesis.tex 
\thispagestyle{empty}             % No page numbers
\calccentering{\unitlength}
\begin{adjustwidth*}{\unitlength}{-\unitlength}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-0.5cm}{-0.5cm}
        \sffamily
        \begin{flushright}
            \thesistypeabbr{} Thesis\\*[0cm]
            \thesistype{}\\
        \end{flushright}
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \noindent
        \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{DTU-Compute-B-UK}\\*[0.5cm]
        \HUGE \thesistitle{}\\*[0.2cm]
        \Huge \thesissubtitle{}\\*[1.2cm]
        \parbox[b]{0.5\linewidth}{%
            \LARGE 
            \thesisauthor{}\\*[0.6cm]% <------------------ change
            \Large
              % <Inserted>
              \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l@{}}
                Supervisors:\\
                Department X; & Department Y;\\
                A.B.          & W.K.\\
                C.D.          & L.J.
              \end{tabular*}\\*[0.6cm]
              % </Inserted>
            \thesislocation{} \the\year
        }
        \hfill\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{DTU-logo-CMYK}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{adjustwidth*}
\normalfont
\normalsize
```

The resulting titlepage looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I could not get it to work. I tried to put in the defined \documentclass and packages, but it is too long. If it is a help I gave a link of the template I am using and both are defined in the preamble - general. tex.